# Not able to install Nuxeo DAM plugin

Tags: nuxeo

The Nuxeo documentation says 'Nuxeo DAM' addon does not require registration. But while installing via nuxeoctl it errors out that its not registered.

Relevant document: https://doc.nuxeo.com/nxdoc/nuxeo-add-ons/

Nuxeo home:          /NuxeoOpenSource/nuxeo/nuxeo-distribution/nuxeo-server-tomcat/target/nuxeo-server-tomcat-10.2-SNAPSHOT
Nuxeo configuration: /NuxeoOpenSource/nuxeo/nuxeo-distribution/nuxeo-server-tomcat/target/nuxeo-server-tomcat-10.2-SNAPSHOT/bin/nuxeo.conf
Include template: /NuxeoOpenSource/nuxeo/nuxeo-distribution/nuxeo-server-tomcat/target/nuxeo-server-tomcat-10.2-SNAPSHOT/templates/common-base
Include template: /NuxeoOpenSource/nuxeo/nuxeo-distribution/nuxeo-server-tomcat/target/nuxeo-server-tomcat-10.2-SNAPSHOT/templates/common
Include template: /NuxeoOpenSource/nuxeo/nuxeo-distribution/nuxeo-server-tomcat/target/nuxeo-server-tomcat-10.2-SNAPSHOT/templates/default
Optional dependencies [nuxeo-web-ui, nuxeo-jsf-ui] will be ignored for 'nuxeo-dam-6.4.1-SNAPSHOT'.

Dependency resolution:
  Installation order (1):        nuxeo-dam-6.4.1-SNAPSHOT
  Packages to download (1):      nuxeo-dam:6.4.1-SNAPSHOT

Do you want to continue (yes/no)? [yes] yes
Downloading [nuxeo-dam-6.4.1-SNAPSHOT]...
Aborting packages change request

Failed commands:
* download (nuxeo-dam-6.4.1-SNAPSHOT)
    Registration required.

Answer (score 1):

What documentation page are you talking about? Please include relevant links when your report a problem.

Downloading some precompiled package from the Nuxeo Marketplace servers requires registration, as it's a service that Nuxeo provides. Note that SNAPSHOT versions of the packages are not available from Nuxeo Marketplace.

You can always compile this software yourself of course.